# cloudera - start hue and import data

Tags: url, cloudera, hue

I am accessing my cloudera manager and I have restarted hue, so I can add data. Is there an url to point me where hue is running. How can access hue in my browser ?

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

you just need to change the port to 8888